# jQuery index(); of specific div with data

Tags: jquery, html, indexing

i have tried to figure out how to get the index() value of a specific div…

Basic HTML:

```
<div class="rsContainer">
    <div class="rsSlide rsActiveSlide">
        <div class="rsContent" data-name="/A"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsSlide">
        <div class="rsContent" data-name="/B"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsSlide">
        <div class="rsContent" data-name="/C"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsSlide">
        <div class="rsContent" data-name="/D"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsSlide">
        <div class="rsContent" data-name="/E"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsSlide">
        <div class="rsContent" data-name="/F"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so here the code i have tried:

```
var pathname = B;
// this is a random one of the data-name values

var currentslide = $(".rsActiveSlide").find(".rsContent").data("name");
// this is active

var rightone = $(".rsContainer").find(".rsContent" + "[data-name='" + pathname +"']");
// this should be the active
// here is the problem, all i need is the index(); of the parent.DIV (.rsSlide)

if (currentslide != pathname) {
    goTo(index-of-rightone's-parent);
}
// so i could do: goTo(index); and the Slider will set the Slide which contains the "rightone" to be active
```

Thx you very much! Any Help is appreciatet…

wbr
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean something like:

```
var rightone = $(".rsContainer")
    .find(".rsContent" + "[data-name='" + pathname +"']")
    .parent().index();
```

|OR| you could do it:

```
var rightone = $(".rsContainer")
    .find(".rsContent" + "[data-name='" + pathname +"']")
    .closest('.rsSlide').index();
```

To keep in mind:

- Indexes are 0 based, meaning the 4th item will ahve an index number of 3
- If there are siblings undesired (of different class names) then you can use a specifier in the index parameter to get ONLY THE INDEX of LIKE elements (see comments)

Comment: I think it is supposed to be `var rightone = $(".rsContainer")
    .find(".rsContent" + "[data-name='" + pathname +"']")
    .closest('.rsSlide'); var index = $('.rsSlide').index(rightone);` As you want to get the index among those class

Comment: @Sushanth-- why? it's not necessary when `.closest('.rsSlide')` will already bring him into a range of sibling `.rsSlide`, according to his HTML. As is shown, it will work with or without any parameter in the index method.

Comment: hi thanks for your help… but:    var rightone = $(".rsContainer").find(".rsContent" + "[data-name='" + pathname +"']").closest('.rsSlide').index(); = 6,     it should be 4 :/

Comment: Sorry my Bad, your are RIGHT! it seem these Slider changes the arrangement every slide so my expectation wasnt right…